# Adding rows of data to a non-spatial table in ArcMap with a SDE SQL Server for Metadata purposes

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to use several non-spatial tables to better organize the large set of feature classes I continually add to a SDE Geodatabase (SQL Server Express).  So I have several tables setup and the relationships between them setup.  Basically the plan is to use these tables to simply add metadata so to speak so the feature classes can be easily reported on.  The tables will show who the owner of the geographic area the data comes from and what type of data it is.  None of this needs to spatial.  Basically I want organization outside of needing to add this metadata type data in every record of the feature class.

However, after creating these non-spatial tables there doesn't seem to be way to add any data to these inside of ArcMap.  The Editor doesn't work since it since there are no spatial layers present.  I've tried arcpy and I only get errors.  Is the only way to use these non-spatial tables is to create some interface outside of ArcMap?  I was think I could use some 3rd Python module to add data directly to SQL Server but have no idea where to find that. Also, how would I create a UI for the Python Scripts?  Any ideas or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a stand alone table in your database through a connection in ArcCatalog so that the table will be registered with the database. Then assign privleges to the table and register as versioned through ArcCatalog.  You should be able to add it to ArcMap and edit it then.

Answer (score 0):

With editing turned on for the table, an extra empty row appears at the end of the table. Just click in it and fill it in, and then tab to the end and a new empty row will appear.

http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Adding_new_records_to_a_table/005s00000015000000/